# Get file name of a URL in PHP

Tags: php

I want to get the file name from a URL. But the problem is it's not ending with an extension.

For example, http://something.com/1245/65/. On clicking this URL, we will get a PDF file. How do I store the file name of that file in a variable?

Comment: Probably use something like cURL with a HEAD request to see what the attachment is named?

Comment: can you please put the exact code here...

Comment: `$curl -iv "url" | less`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
<?php
  header('Content-Type: text/plain');

  $curl = curl_init('http://localhost/fakefile.php');

  curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
  curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
  curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'HEAD');

  if (($response = curl_exec($curl)) !== false)
  {
    if (curl_getinfo($curl, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE) == '200')
    {
      var_dump($response);

      $reDispo = '/^Content-Disposition: .*?filename=(?<f>[^\s]+|\x22[^\x22]+\x22)\x3B?.*$/m';
      if (preg_match($reDispo, $response, $mDispo))
      {
        $filename = trim($mDispo['f'],' ";');

        echo "Filename Found: $filename";
      }
    }
  }

  curl_close($curl);
```

That would parse the `Content-Disposition` line for the **filename=foo.bar** information (assuming it does render the file directly out using this method.)

Comment: better do strtolower($response) , some servers may set so

Comment: @djdance not if you are using *nix or care about case of filename. Better off specifying `i` flag in regex pattern.

Comment: sure, I just saw so on another server (Windows, possibly). And could you give me an example of i flag in regex ;-)

Comment: @djdance append `i` to `$reDispo` variable. E.g. `/.../mi`.

Answer (score 0):

If you issue a `GET` request for `http://something.com/1245/65/` and it returns you a PDF file -- that is, something with `Content-Type = application/pdf` -- you have absolutely *no way* of knowing the actual name of the `.pdf` file that was sent to you.

In the web application that I work on, I *generate* and *combine* PDF files and stream them directly to the browser in response to just such a `GET` request - no actual file even *exists* so there definitely is not filename.

If you are in control of the server you could invent a way to communicate the name to the requester, or if it's your PHP code that wants to know (which runs *on the server*) you could provide some other server-side hook to find the filename.

Comment: I wouldn't say there's definitely not a filename. It depends strongly on the headers included. [`Content-Disposition`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MIME#Content-Disposition) has the ability to specify a filename. And besides, if one's not provided you can always make one up (probably based on time/date combination).

Comment: Good point @Brad and maybe I shouldn't have phrased my answer so strongly, but in the case that I mention in my answer I in fact *lie* in the `Content-Disposition` header.  What I'm really saying is there is no way to really know what's behind any given request, even though it might be exactly determinable for some *particular* situation.

Answer (score 0):

Curiously enough, trying the same code you have above was making my webserver hang too. I replaced this code:

```
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'HEAD');
```

With this:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_NOBODY, true);
```

Answer (score -2):

Say if you have a url

```
$url = 'www/htdocs/lib/inc.php'

 $pathifo = pathinfo($url)// Return Array
```

when you say `$pathinfo['PATHINFO_FILENAME'] //It would output inc`

Comment: You strictly deviate from the example. Read the question.